# No Track output to Azure Compute Emulator

Tags: azure, visual-studio-debugging, azure-web-roles, azure-compute-emulator

I created 1 WebRole and test it with Azure Emulator.
For debugging, I enabled Azure diagnostic and use local storage setting.
In the web MVC project, I add one line of code to log info to Azure compute emulator UI,

```
   public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Trace.TraceInformation(string.Format("now:{0}",DateTime.Now.ToString()));

        return Content("index");
    }
```

When running the web, the the message wasn't be shown on output console as I expected.

[image]

For Web.config, I have this setting for tracing.

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace>
        <listeners>
            <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="AzureDiagnostics">
                <filter type="" />
            </add>
        </listeners>
    </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

I found this issues on internet and try to follow that instruction. It doesn't work for me.

Thank you so much.